# Abstract object not mapped correctly in Elasticsearch using Nest 7.0.0-alpha1

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using NEST (.NET 4.8) to import my data, and I have a problem getting the mapping to work in NEST 7.0.0-alpha1.

I have the following class structure:

```
class LinkActor
{
    public Actor Actor { get; set; }
}

abstract class Actor
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

class Person : Actor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I connect to Elasticsearch this way:

```
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(connection));
connectionSettings.DefaultIndex(indexName);
var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
```

The actual data looks like this:

```
var personActor = new Person
{
    Description = "Description",
    Name = "Name"
};

var linkActor = new LinkActor
{
    Actor = personActor
};
```

And the data is indexed like this:

```
result = client.IndexDocument(linkActor);
```

Using NEST 6.6 I am getting the following data in Elasticsearch 6.5.2:

```
"actor": {
    "name": "Name",
    "description": "Description"
}
```

However when using NEST 7.0.0-alpha1 I get the following data in Elasticsearch 7.0.0:

```
 "actor": {
      "description": "Description"
  }
```

So the data from the concrete class is missing. I am obviously missing / not understanding some new mapping feature, but my attempts with AutoMap has failed:

```
client.Map<(attempt with each of the above classes)>(m => m.AutoMap());
```

Is is still possible to map the data from the concrete class in NEST 7.0.0-alpha1?

Comment: I suspect this is because the property type on `LinkActor` is `Actor` and the serializer uses this as opposed to inspecting the runtime type assigned to the property. Would you mind opening an issue at https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues for this?

Comment: Hi @Russ Cam, Sorry for the late reply. I have opened up an issue [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/3705) and created a repository where I have tried to make it easier to reproduce the problem. The repository is linked in the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround using the NEST.JsonNetSerializer (remember to install this), which allows me to pass a JObject directly:

Connect to Elasticsearch using a pool so you can add the JsonNetSerializer.Default:

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(connection));
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, JsonNetSerializer.Default);
connectionSettings.DefaultIndex(indexName);
var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
```

Convert the linkActor object from above to a JObject (JsonSerializerSettings omitted for clarity, add them to get CamelCasing):

```
var linkActorSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(linkActor);
var linkActorJObject = JObject.Parse(linkActorSerialized);
result = client.IndexDocument(linkActorJObject);
```

This gives the desired result:

```
"actor": {
    "name": "Name",
    "description": "Description"
}
```

It is a workaround, hopefully someone will be able to explain the mapping in the question.